# Choosing a point in matplotlib embedded in wxPython

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I'm trying to select and display data about a point in matplotlib embedded in wxPython.

I've written a minimal example which plots random data.  The code is below.

```
import numpy as np
import wx


from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

class PlotGUI(wx.Frame):
    """Class to display basic GUI elements."""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel = panel

        vert_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.vert_sizer = vert_sizer

        panel.figure = Figure()
        panel.canvas = FigureCanvas(panel, -1, panel.figure)
        self.panel.canvas = panel.canvas

        panel.axes = panel.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.panel.axes = panel.axes

        vert_sizer.Add(panel.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(vert_sizer)
        panel.Fit()

        self.plot_data()

        self.panel.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.display_data)

    def display_data(self, event):
        wx.MessageBox('x :'+str(event.mouseevent.xdata) + 'y: ' + str(event.mouseevent.ydata), 'Info',wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)

    def plot_data(self):
        x = np.arange(10)
        y = np.random.randn(10)
        self.panel.axes.plot(x,y, 'o', picker = 5)

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    GUI = PlotGUI(None)
    GUI.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The first time I click a point, the data is correctly displayed.  However, the next time I click a point, I receive an error.  I tried searching for this error, but I wasn't able to find any relevant threads.  Thanks in advance for the help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pythontology/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_wx.py", line 1137, in _onLeftButtonDown
    self.CaptureMouse()
  File "/home/pythontology/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/_core.py", line 10641, in CaptureMouse
    return _core_.Window_CaptureMouse(*args, **kwargs)
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "!wxMouseCapture::IsInCaptureStack(this)" failed at ./src/common/wincmn.cpp(3271) in CaptureMouse(): Recapturing the mouse in the same window?
```

Comment: Can you test this with one 1.4.0rc2?  I recall something about this going by a while ago and getting fixed.

Comment: but can't find the issue again quickly....

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Does 1.4.0rc2 have a tar.gz for Ubuntu?

I can't seem to find one here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0rc2/

Comment: I also looked here: http://wheels.scikit-image.org/
there only seems to be wheel files for Mac.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~takluyver/+archive/ubuntu/matplotlib-daily

Comment: I just installed 1.4.0rc2 from Github in a virtualenv, and I still seem to receive the same error when I test this code.  Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59440/discussion-between-pythontology-and-tcaswell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of searching, **tcaswell** recommended [this thread](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Nasty-mouse-event-problem-with-wxPython-td25019.html).  After reading this, I found that adding the line `if self.panel.canvas.HasCapture(): self.panel.canvas.ReleaseMouse()` before the wx.MessageBox fixed the issue.

Comment: It would be great if you could this up as an example to go in the mpl docs in the UI embedding example folder.